# Flexslider image <li> dynamically generated by php. Trying to create captions using alt text

Tags: php, jquery, flexslider

I have a vanilla flexslider installation on my site.  The slider operates by cycling through list items in an unordered list.  You can add captions simply by adding a caption container after the list item.  This works well with hard coded images.

The problem I am facing is that my site has multiple sections, with a different slide show for each section.  Instead of hard coding the li elements, I'm generating them with php, so that when a user visits a page, the php figures out which page the user is viewing, and passes that through to the slideshow.  The slideshow then finds the proper image directory and loads all of the images in that directory whether there be two or twenty.  It's much easier than hard coding each slideshow, and it works beautifully.

```
    <?php
        $dh = "image/slideShows/$slideShow/";
        $images = glob($dh . "*.jpg");                       
        foreach($images as $image){
            ?><li><img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="caption text" /></li><?php
        }
        closedir($dh);
    ?>
```

I need to get flexslider to read the alt text for each dynamically generated image, and then place it in a caption container:

```
    <p class="caption">The alt text should show up here.</p>
```

I've tried using:

```
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        controlsContainer: "#slideShowContainer",
        start: function(slider) {
         $('.caption').html(this.alt);
        },
      });
    });
```

and playing around with flexslider's current.slide to no avail.  I've been searching on this all night and I can't seem to figure this one out.  I'm hoping someone here can provide the missing link for me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I figured this out, and it was seriously a matter of over-complication.  All I had to do was call the EXIF data that I was using for the "alt" attribute inside of the caption.  I have no idea why it took me so long to realize this.  Thank you both for your help!**

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the caption container has to be inside the `li`? Are you generating the caption p tag with php as well? if not you could try this inside start: `$(this).after('<p class=caption>'+this.alt+'</p>')`. Otherwise check that `this` inside start is what you think it is.

Comment: I get the same result whether or not the caption container is within the li.  I've tried the code you have provided and it produces no result as is.  I don't know that "this" within start is actually selecting the image.

Comment: you can find out by calling `console.log(this)` and opening in a browser with a console (like Chrome by pressing Ctrl+J, or Firefox with Firebug)

Comment: Ok, I ran the log like so: `start: function(slider){console.log(this) }` and it tells me that the selector is `.slides li` so inside start I ran `$('caption').append('<p class=caption>'+$(this).find('img').attr("alt")+'</p>');` along with a couple of different ways of calling it and appending it, and my caption shows up as "undefined".  I've also tried "src" instead of "alt" and I get the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by "the selector is `.slides li`"? is `this` a selector string and not an object?
In any case shouldn't it be `$(this).append(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have only one `.caption` box?  And you want its contents to change with each slide?

I would try something like:

```
before: function(slider) {
        var slideNumber = slider.currentSlide;
        var alt = $('.slides img').eq(slideNumber).attr('alt');
        $('.caption').html('<p>' + alt + '</p>');
    });
},
```

note that `before` runs at each slide transition, not just once like `start`

**Edit**

OP adjusted the above code (*see comments below*), but still has the "issue mentioned in the comment where the first image doesn't get a caption on it's second and subsequent scrolls"

Perhaps we should be using `after` instead of `before`?  That way we don't need to do `slideNumber+1` (since `before` was making this the previous slide..  You can perhaps remove the `start` function in favor of just doing this above the `flexslider` call

**in `$(window).load(function(){` or `(document).ready(){`:**

```
    var alt = $('.slides img').eq(0).attr('alt'); 
    $('.caption').html('<p>' + alt + '</p>');
```

and within `flexslider()`

```
after:function(slider) { 
    var slideNumber = slider.currentSlide; 
    var alt = $('.slides img').eq(slideNumber).attr('alt'); 
    $('.caption').html('<p>' + alt + '</p>'); 
},
```

Comment: So close. The problem with this is only that the first slide gets no caption, and subsequent slides are off by one, ie., slide 1 = empty, slide 2 = slide 1, slide 3 = slide 2, and so forth.

I tried changing "before" to "start", and as you said, it only fires once.  I then tried adding a second call, the first being "start" and the second being "before".  I also added "+1" `.eq(slidenumber+1)` to even it out.  This works well for the first slide, and throughout the cycle until we get back to the first slide which is then labeled "undefined".

Comment: My code now looks like this:
`start: function(slider) {
      var slideNumber = slider.currentSlide;
      var alt = $('.slides img').eq(slideNumber).attr('alt');
      $('.caption').html('<p>' + alt + '</p>');
    },
    

before: function(slider) {
      var slideNumber = slider.currentSlide;
      var alt = $('.slides img').eq(slideNumber+1).attr('alt');
      $('.caption').html('<p>' + alt + '</p>');
    },`

Comment: sorry, was away from my computer for a while.  Sounds like you got it all figured out?

Comment: Well, figured out to the extent that I was over-complicating it and didn't need to use the jQuery functions to do what I was looking to do.  Your answer did, however, get me where I was trying to go.

Comment: glad to hear it ;-).  Is the final code in your comment above? Perhaps I should edit it into the answer, just in case...

Comment: That code is the furthest I got, although it still suffers from the issue mentioned in the comment where the first image doesn't get a caption on it's second and subsequent scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

```
start: function(slider) {
     var slideNumber = slider.currentSlide; 
     var alt = $('.slides img').eq(slideNumber + 1).attr('alt'); 
     $('.caption').html('<p>' + alt + '</p>'); 
    },
    before: function(slider) {
     var slideNumber = (slider.currentSlide + 1); 
     var alt = $('.slides img').eq(slideNumber + 1).attr('alt'); 
     $('.caption').html('<p>' + alt + '</p>'); 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow! Although this might be the correct answer I think it first needs a little explanation. Perhaps a description explaining what the OP (original poster) did incorrectly. Or you could just explain how your answer differs.